# SQLite3::SQLException : no such column in rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am  facing this SQLite exception error when running my application:

> SQLite3::SQLException at /admin
>
> no such column: subscription_plan.name

This is the controller code, I am facing error:

```
def dashboard
  @number = {
      :month => Subscription.includes(:subscription_plan).where(['subscriptions.created_at > ? AND subscriptions.amount > ? AND subscription_plan.name = ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, 0, 'month']).count,
      :year => Subscription.includes(:subscription_plan).where(['subscriptions.created_at > ? AND subscriptions.amount > ? AND subscription_plan.name = ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, 0, 'year']).count
    }
end
```

This is Subscription model with relation:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscription_plan
end
```

There is no subscription_plan model in my application, but the data to this table is populated through *seeds.rb* file.
As shown in the controller, 'month', 'year' are some of the names in subscription_plan table.

It is working fine with Rails 3.2, i don't know why it's not working with 4.2.6. Please help.

Comment: table name might be subscription_plans, try subscription_plans.name = ?

Comment: Yes, table name is subscription_plans, even it is not working. I don't know how, in the previous version they did the same, it worked.

Comment: try adding references(:subscription_plans) at the end, which was mention in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the table name in condition rather than association name please try

```
Subscription.includes(:subscription_plan).where(['subscriptions.created_at > ? AND subscriptions.amount > ? AND subscription_plans.name = ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, 0, 'month'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this.

```
Subscription.includes(:subscription_plan).where(["subscriptions.created_at > ? AND subscriptions.amount > ? AND subscription_plans.name = ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, 0, 'month']).references(:subscription_plans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference subscription in the `where` clause, note the plural `subscription_plans.name`, and the comment from power is right on about adding the `references(:subscription_plans)`

```
Subscription.includes(:subscription_plan).where(['created_at > ? AND amount > ? AND subscription_plans.name = ?, Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, 0, 'month']).references(:subscription_plans).count
```